# What's the principle of ollydbg's memory breakpoint?

Tags: memory, breakpoints, ollydbg

It seems only 1 memory breakpoint can be set, and it seems doesn't matter at which line the memory breakpoint is set,very weird,anyone can explain?

Answer (score 7):

Memory breakpoints in Ollydbg apply to a block of memory. Note the smallest possible block is typically 4096 bytes (page size). You can select a chunk of code from the disassembler view and set a memory breakpoint on it. You can set Memory Breakpoints on either access or on write. This is internally implemented by using guard pages, which use the PAGE_GUARD modifier. When the memory is accessed (read/write), a STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION exception occurs, which is handled by Ollydbg.

### Example

You want Ollydbg to break when a module is loaded at a particular address (or range). You can goto the Memory view in Ollydbg and select the address range and set a memory breakpoint on it.

Answer (score -2):

OllyDbg use `int 3` to set the breakpoints, and you can set as many breakpoints as you want.

Check if you're really defining breakpoints in the code segment, not in data.